# C++14 Template function forwarding reference deduced explicitly by pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

Explain, please, what's wrong with this code?

An unusual behaviour is that **f3** is working, when deduced implicitly, but is not, when is forcely specialized.

```
template<typename T>
void f1(T x) {}

template<typename T>
void f2(T& x) {}

template<typename T>
void f3(T&& x) {}

int main()
{
  int x = 0;

  f1(x); // ok
  f2(x); // ok
  f3(x); // ok

  f1<int>(x); // ok
  f2<int>(x); // ok
  f3<int>(x); // error
}
```

**VS2017. Compilier message:**

> error C2664: "void f3(T &&)": unable to convert argument 1 from "int" to "T &&"

I thought I'm doing exactly the same specifying **int** explicitly. And only difference that deduction in this case `f3(x);` was done by compiler and in this one `f3<int>(x);` by me.

Comment: The `&&` acts as a forwarding (universal) reference only when deduction is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, please someone correct me if I'm wrong:

Because in case of `f3(x)` the deduced type is `f3<int&>( int& && )`.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I used __PRETTY_FUNCTION __ to see the deduction. Thank you for the direction and thank ATul Singh for pretty function. Here is the link http:://cpp.sh/5xtr7

Answer (score 1):

There is an Errror becuase l-values and l-values references cannot be used  to initialize r-value references. R-values references can only be initialized with r-values only.

You can use **PRETTY_FUNCTION** to get the Function being called along with the arguments that are deduced.

```
f1(a); // ok  deduces to void f1(T) [T = A *]
f2(a); // ok  deduces to void f2(T &) [T = A *]
f3(a); // ok  deduces to void f3(T &&) [T = A *&]


f1<A*>(a); // ok . No Deduction as T already specified void f1(T) [T = A *]
f2<A*>(a); // ok .  No Deduction as T already specified to void f2(T) [T = A *]


f3<A*>(a); // Errror becuase l-values and l-values references 
           // cannot be used  to r-value references.
          // R-values references can only be initialized with r-values only.
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question being asked.

Comment: I think he needed what is wrong in the code and i have pointed out that there is an error in initializing r-values references with l-value . What else is the question as per you ?

Comment: I simplified my snippet a little bit.I thought I'm doing exactly the same specifying int explicitly. And only difference that deduction in this case f3(x); was done by compiler and in this one f3<int>(x); by me.